# how to save web image by sending keystrokes to Firefox using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, firefox, authentication, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to save a web image using the Python bindings of Selenium with Firefox. This image requires authentication to view and I don't know how to get urllib to deal with this authentication:

> IOError: [Errno socket error] [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)

I'm loading the image in Firefox (having authenticated in the browser) and then trying to save it *using the browser* using the Python bindings of Selenium.

Here's a shortened version of the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
URL1 = "https://special.site.ch/webpic/ACR01.jpg"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(URL1)
```

What feels like a natural progression is something like the following:

```
img = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/img[1]')
src = img.get_attribute('src')
urllib.urlretrieve(src, "ACR01.png")
```

However, this does not work for the authentication reason mentioned. What I want to try now is effectively sending `Ctrl` `s`, followed by `Enter` to Firefox in order to save the image using the browser (which is authenticated).

How could I do this?

---

EDIT: A more elaborate attempt featuring a browser profile specification is described below, however, the browser continues to display a dialog with which the script cannot deal:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

URL1 = "https://special.site.ch/webpic/ACR01.jpg"

Firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
Firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
Firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
Firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", os.getcwd())
Firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "image/jpeg")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = Firefox_profile)
driver.get(URL1)

ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "s").perform()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's apply the following trick: get the `src` attribute value of the desired image, open it in the browser via `get()` and use [`save_screenshot()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.save_screenshot) to save it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

URL1 = "https://special.site.ch/webpic/ACR01.jpg"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(URL1)

img = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/img[1]')
src = img.get_attribute('src')
driver.get(src)

driver.save_screenshot("download.jpeg")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. It does indeed work. It'd be nice to be able to access the actual file, but the save dialog appears to be difficult to access using Selenium. I could imagine something awkward using ```xdotool```, but it would be nicer to bottle up the authentication in some way for use with ```urllib.urlretrieve```.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't save the actual image, but rather a screenshot which includes a lot of space around the image.

Comment: This is very clever